# Is it possible to put a ListView that doesn't scroll inside of a scrollview?

Tags: android, listview, android-scrollview

I got a scroll view. I need a list of items inside the scrollview.
I thinking of using a listview and somehow make it display all items and have the scrollview scroll through them.

I think i will run into scrolling problems so my question is, is what i am doing something that is usually done sometimes? if so whats the best way of doing it if not how else should I have a list of items in a scroll view. do I need to create views pro grammatically as I fetch them? it sounds inefficient

Comment: Why do you need/want to put it in a `ScrollView`? Leave it outside of the SV and let the LV handle the scrolling

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I put a ListView into a ScrollView without it collapsing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing)

Comment: @codeMagic because right now there is a view that is above the listview which takes more than half of the screen. so when we put a list view under it, only 1 and half rows of the list view is visible and scrolling through it isn't user friendly

Comment: @code578841441 then this is an issue with the layout. There are better ways to fix this but without seeing what your layout file looks like and what you want to achieve, it's hard to say